# How to create a junit test for a model in a MVC

Tags: java, junit

I'm using the MVC framework for the first time and i want to learn a bit about jUnit tests, i've added my main project to a new package, and i'm trying to implement a new test package to the project where my jUnit test will sit.

My model class is the class that speaks to the most amount of classes so i figured that it would be best to first do a junit test of that. So how do i go about doing simple tests and building up?

Model class

```
public class GateInfoDatabase extends Observable {

    /**
     *  A constant: the number of aircraft gates at the airport.
     */
    public int maxGate = 3;
    private Gate[] gates = new Gate[maxGate];

    public GateInfoDatabase(){
        Gate gate0 = new Gate(0);
        Gate gate1 = new Gate(1);
        Gate gate2 = new Gate(2);

        gates[0] = gate0;
        gates[1] = gate1;
        gates[2] = gate2;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public Gate getGate(int gateNumber){
        Gate result = gates[gateNumber];
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public Gate getGateByMCode(int mCode){
        Gate result = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < gates.length; i++) {
            if(mCode == gates[i].getmCode()) {
                result = gates[i];
                System.out.print(result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public int getStatus(int gateNumber){

        return gates[gateNumber].getStatus();
    }
    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public int getStatusByMCode(int mCode){
        int nStatus = ManagementRecord.FREE;
        Gate result = getGateByMCode(mCode);
        if(result!=null) {
            nStatus = result.getStatus();
        }
        return nStatus;
    }
    /**
     * Returns an array containing the status of all gates.
     * For data collection by the GOC.
     */
    public int[] getStatuses(){

        int[] statuses = new int[maxGate];

        for(int i = 0; i < maxGate; i++){

            statuses[i] = gates[i].getStatus();
        }
        return statuses;
    }

    /**
     * Forward a status change request to the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter. Called to allocate a free gate to the aircraft identified by mCode.
     */
    public void allocate(int gateNumber, int mCode){

        gates[gateNumber].allocate(mCode);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); 

    }

    /**
     * Forward a status change request to the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter. Called to indicate that the expected aircraft has arrived at the gate.
     */
    public void docked(int gateNumber){
        gates[gateNumber].docked();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); 
    }

    /**
     * Forward a status change request to the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter. Called to indicate that the aircraft has departed and that the gate is now free.
     */
    public void departed(int gateNumber){
        gates[gateNumber].departed();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); 
    }

    public int getmCode(int gateNumber){

        return gates[gateNumber].getmCode();
    }

}
```

Test class, that i want to return back 3 due to having 3 gates.

```
public class GateTest {



            GateInfoDatabase model = new GateInfoDatabase();

            @Before
            public void setUp() throws Exception {
            model = new GateInfoDatabase();
            }
            @After
            public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            model = null;
            }
            @Test
            public void testCreate() {
            assertNotNull("Model not created properly", model);
            assertEquals("Initial gate setup is wrong",
              model.maxGate, model.getStatuses().length);
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing isn't simple topic, you should find some tutorial or read book in other to understand how to do it properly.

Simplest way to explain unit testing is to say that it is used for testing classes and methods in other to see if they work properly.

When creating tests if you want to follow conventions you should name your `test class` same as class that you are testing and add Test on the end, so class `Example` should have testing class called `ExampleTest`.

Now inside `ExampleTest` you can test behavior by testing methods, one method **can** and **should** have more tests. When it comes to naming `test methods` there are many different ways, here are few popular:

- `[tested behavior]_[tested input or state]_[expected result]` - I prefer this on my projects
- `[behavior being tested]` - when testing simple things
- `test[behavior being tested]` - I don't like to put test word because its kinda obvious

Now things that you test can be different, and they vary from use case to use case, but something that should be checked always are few standard cases that should always pass(to ensure that method works in first place) and edge cases, for example how methods behave when taking `null`, `0`, `Integer.[MAX/MIN]_VALUE`, empty string/collection/array, negative index and other "critical" values.

For example lets take look at `getGate`, if you write few test cases mentioned above you will see that it fails, -1, 3, or Integer.MAX_VALUE are all valid values that method can take but it will fail for any of those, so now is your choice to improve method in other to handle those, add few if's to check value and if it is valid you can return `Gate` otherwise you should throw exception.

Yes maybe you know that you only have 3 gates and won't try to call it with bigger number, but what if you choose to change that code in 6 months? Will you remember it then?

So make sure to always handle most "fail cases" that are obvious, and as you face new ones make sure to fix them as well. That is the main reason why we do unit tests, in other to ensure that single units of code are work properly, because if those small pieces of code are not doing what they should how can whole program work properly?